# Grid Column Height

Tags: semantic-ui

Is there a way to get columns in one row to be the same size?  I want my ten wide column to be the same height as the six wide column.  Code below.

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ten wide column">
            <div class="ui segment purple inverted">
                Text
                <img class="ui fluid image" src="{{ asset('/img/pic1.jpg') }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="six wide column">
            <div class="ui segment purple inverted">
                Text
                <div class="row">
                    <img class="ui centered image" src="{{ asset('/img/pic2.jpg') }}">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <img class="ui centered image" src="{{ asset('/img/pic3.jpg') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit this: http://codepen.io/ManojAMK/pen/rVzGzQ with full path to your images.

Comment: you should remove the fluid class from the 1st image,  the image from the left colum and the two images from the right column should add together the same height here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/geomorillo/qLtgqqb6/

Answer (score 5):

Semantic 2.0 onwards this is `stretched`.

```html
<div class="ui three column stretched grid">
 <div class='column'>
   A
 </div> 
 <div class='column'>
   B
 </div> 
 <div class='column'>
   C
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like with [Equal Width Columns](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#automatic-column-count) you can use the `equal height grid` to achieve this:

```
<div class="ui equal height grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ten wide purple column">Text</div>
        <div class="six wide red column">
            <div class="row">Text</div>
            <div class="row">Text</div>
            <div class="row">Text</div>
            <div class="row">Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pq1oka3n/1/